# Open source typescript language server

Tags: typescript

Is there an open source typescript language server (uses language server protocol)? And if not currently, I've heard that Microsoft has one in development; will that be open sourced? I see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src/server, but am not exactly sure what it is.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than tsserver?

Comment: Is tsserver open source, and what is it?

Comment: @torazaburo does tsserver use the language server protocol 2.0?

Comment: I believe so, but what problem are you trying to solve? Some TS people lurk here on SO but you may be better off posting on the TS list.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm trying to implement typescript into eclipse che, and just wanted to make sure that there wasn't already one out there before creating a wrapper around typescript lang services or writing my own. And also what is the ts list? It also appears that tsserver doesn't use the language server protocol :/.

Comment: I'm referring to the issues section of the TypeScript github repo.

Comment: @torazaburo Ah TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source of https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src/server is about tsserver.

tsserver is a readline node server but it doesn't use the language server protocol 2.0.

There is a an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11274 for support TypeScript with language server.

Answer (score 0):

There is now this language server (conforming to the Language Server Protocol) which supports TypeScript: https://github.com/sourcegraph/javascript-typescript-langserver